# XML parsing failed in the sqlplus

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, xml, sqlplus

I get following error when executing the query

> Invalid token in '*[count(../*[name(../*)=name(.)])=count(../*) and count(../*)>1'

However when installing the Itstar_xml_util package, it asks for two initial variables one **quot** and another call **gt**, which form the initial structure of the `XML`, I believe that is causing the error, someone knows how to configure correctly?

```
SQL> @C:\instantclient_11_2\itstar_xml_util.pxk
     Packge created.
     Enter value for quot: ?
     Enter value for gt: ?
```

Also follow the query...

```
SQL > declare
      l_sql_string varchar2(32000);
      l_xml xmltype;
      l_json xmltype;
      begin
      l_sql_string := 'select DESCRICAO from VEI_TIPO_VEICULO';
      l_xml := 'itstar_xml_util.sql2xml(l_sql_string);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getclobval());
      l_json := itstar_xml_util.xml2json(l_xml);
      dbms_output.put_line(l_json.getclobval());
      end;
      /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call

```
SET DEFINE OFF
```

before installing the package to ensure that `&quot` and `&gt` are not recognized as substitution variables. See also [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-440C19CB-297E-4630-894C-FA7939153CD6).